# Dynamically Create Different Session Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I was wondering if it was possible to dynamically create different session variables with different names based on a variable?

I attempted to accomplish this way but does not seem to like my variable

```
protected void myGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("MyLinkButton");
    Label options = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("MyLabel");
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRoow)
    {
    Session[lb] = options;  
//I was trying to use this to create Session Variables with Different Names Dynamically
    }

}
```

So my end result I would have the following sessions with out having to manually create all of them.

```
Session["Value"] = "MyOption"
Session["Value1"] = "MyOption1"
Session["Value2"] = "MyOption2"
Session["Value3"] = "MyOption3"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the Session for each of these items?  Why not store the collection of data in the Session (or better yet ViewState) and then get the correct item from the collection when the user clicks a button?

Comment: I edited my question to show what end result I was attempting to accomplish and I was hoping that I would just perform validations throguhout my page based on these session values. Not sure about viewstate will have to try that and see if it will work

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, there might be a better solution than creating all these sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of sections. For exaple:

```
List<string> sections=GetSectionsList();
```

The for each item in your list create a Session variable and populate with the status, something like this:

```
foreach(string section in sections)
{
   Session[section] = GetSectionStatus(section);
}
```

Then onload of each section check for the sections session value and act accordingly. But a piece of advice there use session for this situation only if the sections are considerably less in number say 2 to 5, else a db call on load of each section would be better.

Comment: Thanks Shashank basically I have an application and it is divided into sections on a landing page which is a gridview that shows the section\status of the application. If the status is submitted I dont want that to be able to load that "sections".aspx page so i figured I could create a few sessions based of the values in the gridview and then do a quick session check and redirect them based on that.

Comment: Correct me if I understood it incorrectly. You have a few sections on your grid along with their individual statuses. And if the status is submitted then you do not want to allow the user to redirect to that section. If my understanding is correct then tell me how does a user navigate to the respective section (click of a link button?, where does it lie on each row of the grid or a common button that will sequentially take you to un-finished sections?).

Comment: the section on the grid is a link once clicked i append a url to the value of the section. I am disabling the link so the user can not click the section once it is submitted however if you were to manually browse to the page it will still allow you hence the reason why I would like to perform a simple check with a session depending if it is submitted or not

Comment: Ok then its simple create a list of all the sections, then for each item in the list create session values. The on page load of each section just check for the specific session value.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on our discussion. Please mark it as answer if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the response yes I decided to do the db call, I was approaching this the wrong way from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it backward.  Since you are in the RowDataBound Event, clearly you are data binding.  So save the data in `Session["DataSource"]` or something like that, instead of re-creating the data set when you bind it row by row.

I suggest ViewState because it's only valid for that page.  If you don't plan on using the data outside of that page, there's no reason to add it to Session.

What are you using the Session data for?

Comment: I am using the session to allow or not allow access to other pages based on the value of the session

Comment: not sure what you mean by ["DataSource"]... I was hoping to have Session[gridviewrowvalue] = gridview different row value

Comment: That's not a good idea at all.  Look up the Membership Provider and Roles.  MSFT has already created the wheel here, you've just got to attach it to your code.

Comment: By not a good idea is that not possible? because for the small application I am doing I doubt it will make any sense that I use the membership provider and Roles just for this simple task

Comment: If you have more roles than "Admin" and "User", I suggest using a framework.  Applications have a way of growing in scope as they are used, and your "small" application could become a critical application that grows.  You'll want a solid foundation to expand from.